# Uploader de images de type SVG drupal 7

Tags: svg, drupal-7

I want to know how to upload images SVG type to a content type on Drupal 7
????

Hello everyone, I want to know how to upload images SVG type to a content type on Drupal 7
????

Comment: I added a reply, but you might want to tell us what you have tried and didn't work when asking for help. Otherwise we might think you want us to google for you... which we may find is **not** fair.

Comment: Paste your tries please

Answer (score 1):

From a discussion on Drupal SE:

> The Image widget internally allows (and silently enforces post Drupal 6) the use of only the png, gif, jpg and/or jpeg extensions. So, while you can remove an extension from a field, eg, I have removed gif from most of my implementations to avoid anything animated, you can't add any to this list. I would imagine this is because it in itself displays the image after being uploaded and didn't want to break any displays in older IE browsers in the actual form (plus, who knows how image styles would work on them as well :)

Thread:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98216/adding-svg-file-extension-drupal-gets-stuck

There is an open discussion to include support for `svg` in Drupal 8, as part of the support for HTML5, but still nothing clear (as far as I now)

https://drupal.org/node/1014816

Good luck,